# How would I find the common ratio to determine the sum of the given geometric serie:

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

How would I find the common ratio to compute the sum of the given geometric serie: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty= \frac{(8^n+2^n)}{9^n}$$

Comment: Hi, welcome.  Do you need to find “the” common ratio?  Or could you do two sums separately?

Comment: Hi Greg, I didn't read it properly and forgot to explain the common ratio part, but  like Matthew has suggested I think you might find you need to separate your sum into two geometric series and hence have two common ratios to determine, which can be done as my answer outlines https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note the evaluation of the relevant *finite* summation:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{N}{c}^{n}={\frac {{c}^{N+1}}{c-1}}-{\frac {c}{c-1}} \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(0)$$

And then observe that your sum is the sum of two such summations,the key difference being, these are **infinite**:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {{8}^{n}+{2}^{n}}{{9}^{n}}}=\sum _{n=1}^{
\infty } \left( {\frac {8}{9}} \right) ^{n}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
 \left(\frac {2}{9} \right) ^{n}
$$
We then simply set $c_1=\frac {8}{9}$ and $c_2=\frac {2}{9}$, and substitute the infinite upper bound for our sum with a variable $N$, like we see in the evaluation of the finite sum $(0)$:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{
N }  {c_1}  ^{n}+\sum _{n=1}^{N }
 c_2 ^{\,n}={\frac {{c_1}^{N+1}}{c_1-1}}-{\frac {c_1}{c_1-1}}+{\frac {{c_2}^{N+1}}{c_2-1}}-{\frac {c_2}{c_2-1}}$$

Our final step is the part for which one of the fundamental principles of calculus is required, we evaluate the limit for our variable $N$ as it becomes infinite:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{
\infty } \left( {\frac {8}{9}} \right) ^{n}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
 \left(\frac {2}{9} \right) ^{n}
=\lim _{N\rightarrow \infty }\Biggl(\sum _{n=1}^{
N } \left( {\frac {8}{9}} \right) ^{n}+\sum _{n=1}^{N }
 \left(\frac {2}{9} \right) ^{n}
\Biggr)=\lim _{N\rightarrow \infty }\Biggl({\frac {{(\frac {8}{9})}^{N+1}}{\frac {8}{9}-1}}-{\frac {(\frac {8}{9})}{(\frac {8}{9})-1}}+{\frac {{(\frac {2}{9})}^{N+1}}{\frac {2}{9}-1}}-{\frac {\frac {2}{9}}{\frac {2}{9}-1}}\Biggr)=\frac{58}{7}$$

Comment: When computing the limit, wouldn't the exponent (N+1) on both the (8/9) and (2/9)  make the limit tend to infinity? Also, could I compute

Comment: No compute the values for $(\frac{x}{y})^N$ for $N=1,2,3,...$ up to as large as you require to convince yourself that when $x \leq y$ the difference between successive values of $N$ is getting smaller and smaller or is nothing at all (when $x=y$), and gets larger and larger when $x \gt y$